# How to compile require statements?

Tags: javascript, commonjs, es6-modules, es6-module-loader, transpiler

I have the following require statements in my .js file which gets transpiled from ES2017, however, the browser still does not recognize these commands (require is not defined). How can I solve this?

```
  this.e = require('../../e.js'),
  this.a = require('../../a.js'),
  this.cb = require('../../cb.js'),
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not recognize"?

Comment: I am getting an error in the console saying require() is not defined.

Comment: I believe, you need System.js, because browser-js doesn't have require (that's a function for node.js).

Answer (score 1):

Transpiling your code is not enough to make it work in a browser. You will need a build system like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle your code into one (or multiple) files that you can include in your web app.

For example `webpack` can first transpile your code using `babel` and then bundle your whole app into 1 file which will run in the browser without a problem (as it won't have any `require` anymore).

Another solution you can use is `type="module"` in your script tag:

```
<script type="module" src="/my/app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
import a from "../../a.js";
...
```